# Force IKVMC Conversion of JARs to DLL?

Tags: c#, java, .net, jar

I'm attempting to use IKVMC to convert a some "out of the box" JAR files our researchers have used to DLLs that I can use it within our C# project. While I was able to get this to successfully complete for some JARs -- one's that contain a Main() method get converted to .exe files (as documented within IKVMC). I don't know how to deal with those.

Does anyone know how I could either:

1. Use the output EXE in my C# application
2. Get IKVMC to generate the JAR into a DLL eventhough the JAR contains a Main() method

**IKVMC command prompt output:**

```
ikvmc xom.jar
Note IKVMC0004: using main class "nu.xom.Info" based on jar mainfest
Note IKVMC0002: output file is "xom.exe"
```

Comment: An `.exe` should be an assembly like any other. Have you just tried dropping it into your project?

Comment: @millimoose See my comment in the answer below. Thanks for the help. I wanted to get at the classes/objects in the JAR and not the EXE if I could ultimately avoid it -- as not all the code was needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EXE files are just DLLs with an entry point. You can reference EXEs in your C# project the same way you reference an external DLL file.

Comment: Absolutely true. I pretty much blew my coworkers' minds once when I fired up IronPython, imported an application's .exe assembly and proceeded to remix the main loop so that it did things in a different order from how the compiled `main()` did.

Comment: @mike-atlas I was able to add the EXE -- but i ended up also figuring out how to force IKVMC to covert the JAR to a DLL. Just needed to add `-target:library` in the command line argument.

Answer (score 2):

To force IKVMC to output to a DLL add `-target:library` to the command line args.

```
ikvmc -target:library xom.jar
```

Found the answer by stumbling upon this: [Using Java Classes in your .NET Application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13549/Using-Java-Classes-in-your-NET-Application)

Answer (score 2):

I understand this is already answered but if you want to control the name of dll and extend bharris9's answer then you can use an out parameter.

```
ikvmc -out:myapp.dll -target:library xom.jar
```

Source: http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/ikvmc.html#Options